# Point different domains to different Docker containers on a single EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a simple NodeJS site running inside a Docker container, with its ports mapped to port 80 on the host. I have a domain pointing to the IP of the EC2 instance, and everything is working as expected.

If I want to run another, separate NodeJS site from a Docker container on the same instance, how can I map specific domain names to specific Docker containers?

Eg, let's assume the IP of my EC2 instance is 22.33.44.55 and my domains are domain-a.com and domain-b.com. My dockerized NodeJS applications are siteA and siteB.

domain-a.com is configured to point to 22.33.44.55. siteA is listening on that IP address to port 80 - this is what I currently have.

domain-b.com is configured to point to 22.33.44.55. I want this traffic mapped to the siteB Docker container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could setup a nginx reverse proxy on the host and bind to seperate ports. The question/and answer on this article explain it quite nicely so I won't repeat it all:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-bind-multiple-domains-ports-80-and-443-to-docker-contained-applications

Comment: Thanks, that does seem like it describes my situation well. Before going down the nginx route, do you know if it's possible / worth the effort without the need for nginx / reverse proxy?

Comment: Not sure how it would be possible without some sort of reverse proxy setup - nginx, haproxy etc. Not saying its not possible, but offhand nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen how much ngninx costs - will hold out for an answer that's $1500 cheaper!

Comment: both nginx and haproxy are free and open source, at least a version of them are.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'd been looking at nginx plus. Thanks again.

Comment: And, I assume [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io) also fits this task. Have you had experience with it? What is more easy to set up and configure: nginx or Traefik?

Comment: @Suncatcher - Traefik would almost certainly solve the same problem but wasn't much of an option 3 years ago. As far as which is easier to setup, your're better off asking a separate SO question specific to your needs.