# How to use name of container to resolve to its IP in nginx's upstream server?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running 2 Docker containers on a host. In my first container, I started it this way:

```
docker run -d --name site-a -p 127.0.0.1:3000:80 nginx
```

This maps the port 80 to the host machine's port 3000. It also has a name called `site-a`, which I want to use it in another container.

Then in my other container, which is a main reverse proxy container, I configured the nginx's configuration to have an upstream pointing the the first container (`site-a`):

```
upstream my-site-a {
    server site-a:80;
}
```

I then run the reverse proxy container this way:

```
docker run -d --name reverse-proxy -p 80:80 nginx
```

So that my reverse-proxy container will serve from `site-a` container.

However, there are 2 problems here:

1. The upstream in my nginx configuration doesn't work when I use `server site-a:80;`. How can I get
   nginx to resolve the alias "site-a" to the IP of `site-a` container?
2. When starting site-a container, I followed an answer at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519441/point-different-domains-to-different-docker-containers-on-a-single-ec2-instance)
   and bound it to the host machine's port 3000 with this: `-p 127.0.0.1:3000:80` Is this neccessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your containers to be mutually reachable via their name, you need to add them to the same network.

First create a network with this command:

```
docker network create my-network
```

Then, when running your containers, add the `--network` flag like this:

```
docker run -d --name site-a -p 127.0.0.1:3000:80 --network my-network nginx
```

Of course you need to do the same thing to both containers.

As per your second question, there's no need to map the port on your host with the `-p` flag as long as you don't want to reach `site-a`'s container directly from your host.

Of course you still need to use the `-p` flag on the reverse proxy container in order to make it reachable.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine multiple containers to more complex infrastructure it's time to move to more complex technologies. Basically you have the choice between docker-compose and docker stack. Kubernetes could also be an option but it's more complicated.

That techniques provide solutions for container discovery and internal name resolving.

I suggest to use docker stack. Instead of compose it has no additional requirements beside docker.